# Get mime type for MediaSource.isTypeSupported

Tags: html, ffmpeg, mime-types, ffprobe, media-source

How do I get the Mime type [I need to pass to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/isTypeSupported) `MediaSource.isTypeSupported` with ffprobe/ffmpeg?

For instance, on my computer, that returns `true`:

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"')
```

while that doesn't

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4')
```

I'm not sure how to get what would correspond to the `avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2` part for a given video. [Here](https://gist.github.com/granoeste/8727308) is a larger list of what this part may look like.

`ffprobe -show_streams -i video.mp4` returns a number of interesting informations, including

```
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/40
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
```

and

```
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
```

I'm not sure I should go with `'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.0x31637661,mp4a.0x6134706d"'` since this returns `false` and I don't know if it's because it's not the excepted argument or because the video is indeed not supported.

Answer (score 10):

Using [Bento4](https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4), I can get the Mime type with

```
mp4info video.mp4 | grep Codec
```

That will return something like

```
Codecs String: avc1.64001F
Codecs String: mp4a.40.2
```

And then do

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2"')
```

which returns `true` :)

Bento4 is focussed on `mp4` so I'm not sure how it'd work on other formats

Comment: it was also worth noting for me that the isTypeSupported command can be run in the dev console prior to starting anything

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a super old questions, but I recently ran into this myself. I had a hard time finding an easy way to get the proper MIME string so I wrote a simple [Node.js CLI program](https://gitlab.com/dominicp/get-video-mime/) to do it using the excellent [mp4box.js](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/).

You use it like this:

```sh
$ npx get-video-mime your-video-file.mp4

[22:28:37] Getting MIME for 1 file(s)...
[22:28:38] MIME for your-video-file.mp4 detected as: video/mp4; codecs="hev1.1.6.L120.90,mp4a.6b"; profiles="isom,iso2,mp41"
[22:28:38] Finished processing all files.
```

Hopefully it will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Any other way to convert the `0x31637661` part to `avc1.64001F`?

EDIT: since I have not installed Apple's XCode and no intention to - I have found the javascript project of MP4Box the best way to find the codec information in the right format:

http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/filereader.html

Comment: I dunno. What's holding you back on Bento4? I agree it'd be nice to have an answer with more common tools, and that works out of `mp4`. Bento4 did the job for me so I stopped looking. (Also you should write that in the comments vs the answer :) )

Comment: On OSX to get Bento4 installed (xbuild.proj) I should download Apple's Xcode, with the insane file size of 4.4GB!!!  After a whole lot more searching it looks like MP4BOX can output the right Mime/codec format needed for the HTML5 video tag. They even have a JavaScript version an a GUI floating around https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/

Comment: Oh yeah I already had Xcode so didn't noticed. Yes MP4BOX seems quite good as well. Don't hesitate to share your response if you find how to do it with MP4BOX :)

Comment: Nice timing! OK I found this page http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/filereader.html It's the javascript version of MP4Box. If you choose >file loading you can see the desired codec info in the > movie view tab. Can you do me a favor and check the result against your Bento4 results? Cheers! btw MP4Box needs XTools installed too :-( I hope this .js version is the solution..

Comment: I've found the results to be the same (for that, and other things like fragments byte positions etc) Their UI is nice to check things and experiment, but there's more work to do to get this data from a script. I think they have a Java librairy that should do the work, but I haven't touched java in a while!

Comment: Thanks! So you agree that for the OP's question (just get the `'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"'`info), this is by far the fastest and easiest solution right? I mean no installing of additional software, just run JS from the browser to get the codec info from local files so one can use them in the HTML5 video tags.

Comment: well it depends of the use case:
- if this is a one time thing, then probably yes, just use their UI
- if you need this info as part of a script that does other things as well, then no. You might be able to run their javascript in your client, but there's a lot of situations where you'd rather just send the final info to the client vs loading this entire script

I was looking for something I could run on my server (that's why my first guess was ffmpeg/ffprobes)

Answer (score 1):

***if you want it quick and easy, run this***

```html
<input id=input type=file><br><br>
<script type=module>
      import MP4Box from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mp4box/+esm';
      input.onchange    = async e=>{
            var buf         = await input.files[0].arrayBuffer();
            buf.fileStart   = 0;
            mp4.appendBuffer(buf);
      }//onchange
      var mp4       = MP4Box.createFile();
      mp4.onReady   = info=>document.body.append(info.mime+' , '+MediaSource.isTypeSupported(info.mime));
</script>
```

no downloads, no installs, you can copy and paste the mime whereever you want, bookmark the page or take the code away with you

mp4box's onready function is automatically called when the moov box has been processed and meta data about the file is known and we pop out a convenient mimecodec for use with mediasource

now i dont know really know a lot about codecs and containers and naming conventions, so help me out will y'all, but

in terms of which codecs are actually supported by [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), its pretty safe to stick with h.264 (mp4) for video, its the audio that usually causes a problem, chrome basically only supports aac lc (low complexity) or just aac, [MPEG-4 audio object types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#sect3), and im not sure about other browsers, firefox also supports it

ive not looked into other formats yet, but webm is another viable streaming option

edit:

i updated the method, its less lines of code and works better on all files that last one struggled for files push 1GB

ive done quite a bit of research into streaming video and audio recently, if you want to discuss more in a chat style environment head over to stackoverflows javascript chatroom https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript i'd be happy to share research and code, maybe people can take up where i left off, theres still a lot to be done and a crowd sourcing colaboration is probably the best option