# Which of these values can be detected in Media Source Extensions

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, media-source, adaptive-bitrate

I am trying to detect following information about the stream in Media Source Extensions

- Audio/Video Bitrate
- Bandwidth
- IP address of the stream
- Stream information like format

I have been reading the documentations but I could not find any direct references to these. Is it possible to extract these information?

Comment: are you trying to do it on the client or on the server? Audio/Video Bitrate, format sound easier to do on the server.
IP address of the stream == IP of the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Bandwidth: you have to infer it from the client, measuring how long it takes to download packets of known size (you can get the size from the headers as well) as do some simple math.
- Audio/Video Bitrate & Stream information like format: sounds easier to get on the server and send this information, if that's possible for you.

  - on the server, you can use ffmpeg/ffprobe to get byterate, and Bento4 to get type (see [Get mime type for MediaSource.isTypeSupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616494/get-mime-type-for-mediasource-istypesupported))
  - if you have to do it on the client, you can check out [MP4Box](http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/filereader.html)

IP: ie client IP? it's in the request header and there are a number of SO questions about it.

Comment: My script would be on the client side.

Comment: cool, so depending on your environment, you'll be able to access different utilities. What's your stack on? If you're on node, you can check out fluent-ffmpeg that wraps nicely ffmpeg and ffprobes